# Messages are not displayed after adding pagination to the project FreeMarker template error

Tags: java, spring, web, web-applications, freemarker

In the application, there is a common page with messages, where all messages of all users are displayed and there is a separate page(user profile) where only messages of the logged user are visible. Before I added pagination on the page, everything worked, but now everything is fine only on the main page, the messages and page numbers are visible, but if you open the page(user profile) with the logged user, page numbers and messages are not displayed, instead pages gives an error FreeMarker template error.

main.ftl is the main page with all messages on which everything works, the displaying of all messages described in messageList.ftl.

Error

```
ERROR 6588 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] freemarker.runtime                       : Error executing FreeMarker template

freemarker.core._MiscTemplateException: When calling macro "pager", required parameter "url" (parameter #1) was specified, but had null/missing value.

----
Tip: If the parameter value expression on the caller side is known to be legally null/missing, you may want to specify a default value for it with the "!" operator, like paramValue!defaultValue.
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: #macro pager url page  [in template "parts/pager.ftl" in macro "pager" at line 1, column 1]
    - Reached through: @p.pager url, page  [in template "parts/messageList.ftl" at line 4, column 1]
    - Reached through: #include "parts/messageList.ftl"  [in template "userMessages.ftl" at line 40, column 5]
    ~ Reached through: #nested  [in template "parts/common.ftl" in macro "page" at line 18, column 1]
    ~ Reached through: @c.page  [in template "userMessages.ftl" at line 3, column 1]
```

userMessages.ftl

```
    <#import "parts/common.ftl" as c>

<@c.page>
<h3>${userChannel.username}</h3>
    <#if !isCurrentUser>
        <#if isSubscriber>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="/user/unsubscribe/${userChannel.id}">Unsubscribe</a>
        <#else>
        <a class="btn btn-info" href="/user/subscribe/${userChannel.id}">Subscribe</a>
        </#if>
    </#if>
<div class="container my-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title">Subscriptions</div>
                    <h3 class="card-text">
                        <a href="/user/subscriptions/${userChannel.id}/list">${subscriptionsCount}</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-title">Subscribers</div>
                    <h3 class="card-text">
                        <a href="/user/subscribers/${userChannel.id}/list">${subscribersCount}</a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <#if isCurrentUser>
        <#include "parts/messageEdit.ftl" />
    </#if>

    <#include "parts/messageList.ftl" />
</@c.page>
```

pager.ftl

```
<#macro pager url page >
<#if page.getTotalPages() gt 7>
    <#assign
    totalPages = page.getTotalPages()
    pageNumber = page.getNumber() + 1
    head = (pageNumber > 4)?then([1, -1], [1, 2, 3])
    tail = (pageNumber < totalPages - 3)?then([-1, totalPages], [totalPages - 2, totalPages - 1, totalPages])
    bodyBefore = (pageNumber > 4 && pageNumber < totalPages - 1)?then([pageNumber - 2, pageNumber - 1], [])
    bodyAfter = (pageNumber > 2 && pageNumber < totalPages - 3)?then([pageNumber + 1, pageNumber + 2], [])
    body = head + bodyBefore + (pageNumber > 3 && pageNumber < totalPages - 2)?then([pageNumber], []) + bodyAfter + tail
    >
<#else>
    <#assign body = 1..page.getTotalPages()>
</#if>
<div class="mt-3">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Pages</a>
        </li>
        <#list body as p>
            <#if (p - 1) == page.getNumber()>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
                </li>
            <#elseif p == -1>
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">...</a>
                </li>
            <#else>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${p - 1}&size=${page.getSize()}" tabindex="-1">${p}</a>
                </li>
            </#if>
        </#list>
    </ul>

    <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Quantity</a>
        </li>
        <#list [5, 10, 25, 50] as c>
            <#if c == page.getSize()>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">${c}</a>
                </li>
            <#else>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="${url}?page=${page.getNumber()}&size=${c}" tabindex="-1">${c}</a>
                </li>
            </#if>
        </#list>
    </ul>
</div>
```

messageList.ftl

```
<#include "security.ftl">
<#import "pager.ftl" as p>

<@p.pager url page />

<div class="card-columns" id="message-list">
    <#list page.content as message>
        <div class="card my-3" data-id="${message.id}"/>
            <#if message.filename??>
                <img src="/img/${message.filename}" class="card-img-top" />
            </#if>
            <div class="m-2">
                <span>${message.text}</span><br/>
                <i>#${message.tag}</i>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                <a href="/user-messages/${message.author.id}">${message.authorName}</a>
                <#if message.author.id == currentUserId>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/user-messages/${message.author.id}?message=${message.id}">
                        Edit
                    </a>
                </#if>
            </div>
        </div>
    <#else>
        No message
    </#list>
</div>

<@p.pager url page />
```

common.ftl

```
<#macro page>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <#include "navbar.ftl">
<div class="container mt-5">
<#nested>
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
</#macro>
```

main.ftl

```
<#import "parts/common.ftl" as c>

<@c.page>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <form method="get" action="/main" class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" name="filter" class="form-control" value="${filter?ifExists}" placeholder="Search by tag" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<#include "parts/messageEdit.ftl" />

<#include "parts/messageList.ftl" />

</@c.page>
```

MainController.java

```
package coding.domain.controller;

import coding.domain.domain.Message;
import coding.domain.domain.User;
import coding.domain.repos.MessageRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableDefault;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired
    private MessageRepo messageRepo;

    @Value("${upload.path}")
    private String uploadPath;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String greeting(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "greeting";
    }

    @GetMapping("/main")
    public String main(
            @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "") String filter,
            Model model,
            @PageableDefault(sort = { "id" }, direction = Sort.Direction.DESC) Pageable pageable
    ) {
        Page<Message> page;

        if (filter != null && !filter.isEmpty()) {
            page = messageRepo.findByTag(filter, pageable);
        } else {
            page = messageRepo.findAll(pageable);
        }

        model.addAttribute("page", page);
        model.addAttribute("url", "/main");
        model.addAttribute("filter", filter);
        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping("/main")
    public String add(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
            @Valid Message message,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
    ) throws IOException {
        message.setAuthor(user);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            Map<String, String> errorsMap = ControllerUtils.getErrors(bindingResult);

            model.mergeAttributes(errorsMap);
            model.addAttribute("message", message);
        } else {
            saveFile(message, file);

            model.addAttribute("message", null);

            messageRepo.save(message);
        }

        Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();

        model.addAttribute("messages", messages);

        return "main";
    }

    private void saveFile(@Valid Message message, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        if (file != null && !file.getOriginalFilename().isEmpty()) {
            File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);

            if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
                uploadDir.mkdir();
            }

            String uuidFile = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            String resultFilename = uuidFile + "." + file.getOriginalFilename();

            file.transferTo(new File(uploadPath + "/" + resultFilename));

            message.setFilename(resultFilename);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/user-messages/{user}")
    public String userMessges(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser,
            @PathVariable User user,
            Model model,
            @RequestParam(required = false) Message message
    ) {
        Set<Message> messages = user.getMessages();

        model.addAttribute("userChannel", user);
        model.addAttribute("subscriptionsCount", user.getSubscriptions().size());
        model.addAttribute("subscribersCount", user.getSubscribers().size());
        model.addAttribute("isSubscriber", user.getSubscribers().contains(currentUser));
        model.addAttribute("messages", messages);
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        model.addAttribute("isCurrentUser", currentUser.equals(user));

        return "userMessages";
    }

    @PostMapping("/user-messages/{user}")
    public String updateMessage(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User currentUser,
            @PathVariable Long user,
            @RequestParam("id") Message message,
            @RequestParam("text") String text,
            @RequestParam("tag") String tag,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
    ) throws IOException {
        if (message.getAuthor().equals(currentUser)) {
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(text)) {
                message.setText(text);
            }

            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(tag)) {
                message.setTag(tag);
            }

            saveFile(message, file);

            messageRepo.save(message);
        }

        return "redirect:/user-messages/" + user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As exception describe you can use [default operator](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing_default)

> Synopsis: unsafe_expr!default_expr

In your case:

```
 ${url|"/main")
```

Also you can set default in your [macro's parameter](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_macro.html):

> param1, param2, ...etc.: the name of the local variables store the parameter values (not expression), optionally followed by = and the default value (that's an expression). The default value can even be another parameter, for example <#macro section title label=title

In your case:

```
 <#macro pager url="/main" page >
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where do I need to paste it? In every ftl files or only in pager.ftl?